# How do I refresh a parent page from within a custom user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

I have an aspx page that contains several custom .ascx controls. The aspx has a main menu down the left hand side. The menu is generated on page load within a method called getmenu().

The problem I have is that on the page there is also some custom controls and these are causing the parent page to postback, which loses my menu.

In the parent page, whenever a click is done, I usually initialise the getmenu() method again and it rebuilds it but within the controls I can't access the method.

I would like to know how I can refresh the parent page so it generates the menu like it was never gone.

This is the getMenu() method within the masterpage of the parent page:

```
    public void getMenu()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

     // get the connection
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnection.GetConnectionString()))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("PL_Menu_Module_Get", conn);
                    sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);

                    sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;

                    da.Fill(table);

                }



                // populate the parent node first

                DataView view = new DataView(table);

                view.RowFilter = "ParentMenuId is NULL";

                foreach (DataRowView row in view) //Level 1
                {
                    CreateDiv(row["MenuName"].ToString(), row["MenuUrl"].ToString(), 1, row["ParentMenuId"].ToString(), row["MenuId"].ToString());

                    DataView child = new DataView(table);
                    child.RowFilter = "ParentMenuId =" + row["MenuId"].ToString();

                    foreach (DataRowView rowchild in child) //Level 2
                    {
                        CreateDiv(rowchild["MenuName"].ToString(), rowchild["MenuUrl"].ToString(), 2, rowchild["ParentMenuId"].ToString(), rowchild["MenuId"].ToString());

                        DataView child2 = new DataView(table);
                        child2.RowFilter = "ParentMenuId =" + rowchild["MenuId"].ToString();
                        foreach (DataRowView rowchild2 in child2) //Level 3
                        {
                            CreateDiv(rowchild2["MenuName"].ToString(), rowchild2["MenuUrl"].ToString(), 3, rowchild2["ParentMenuId"].ToString(), rowchild2["MenuId"].ToString());
                        }

                    }

                }



            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                ExceptionHandling.SQLException(ex, constPageID, constIsSiteSpecific);
            }
}
```

The control is added to the default.aspx which uses that master page.

Comment: Just to add to that; I changed the getmenu() to a static public void and also the create div which is was calling so I could call this method from within my .ascx but then it error'd on the line which adds the new div to the page as it required an object reference.

Answer (score 0):

While I have serious doubts about your setup based on the description that you gave, one technique that you can use is the event system.

In your custom control, you can have the event declaration:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

And the condition under which you want to raise that event:

```
On Control Load {
    if(MyEvent != null) {
        MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Then your parent page can subscribe to your control's event:

```
myCustomControl.MyEvent += (object, sender) => Refresh();
```

Comment: When you say serious doubts, which part are you referring to? You can't tell me that I am the first person to ever want to call a method on a page from a user control?